# Using unordered_map of member function pointers with inheritance, using std:function

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, function-pointers

I'm trying to create and use an unordered_map of member function pointers, as part of an interface, which are inherited and used by child classes.  The ultimate goal is to allow the child classes to be used by scripts ("scriptable"), so that their functions can be invoked by text "commands."

I'm having problems with the syntax, and difficulties involving both member function pointers and their inheritance and use.  I've tried many variations, but this is a complex and subtle issue, as my googling has shown me.

The interface:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class IScriptable
{
    public:
        virtual void Init() = 0;
        bool Run_Script_Command(string i_Command, vector<string> i_Arguments);
    protected:
        void Register_Command_Function_Pair(string i_Command, function<void(const IScriptable&, vector<string>)> i_Function);

        unordered_map<string, function<void (const IScriptable&, vector<string>)>> m_Command_Functions;
};

bool IScriptable::Run_Script_Command(string i_Command, vector<string> i_Arguments)
{
    if (m_Command_Functions.find(i_Command) != m_Command_Functions.end())
    {
        (m_Command_Functions[i_Command])(*this, i_Arguments);
    }
    else
    {
        return(false);
    }

    return(true);
}

void IScriptable::Register_Command_Function_Pair(string i_Command, function<void(const IScriptable&, vector<string>)> i_Function)
{
    m_Command_Functions[i_Command] = i_Function;
}
```

The child object:

```
class Child : public IScriptable
{
    public:
        virtual void Init();
    protected:
        void Foo(vector<string> parms); // The function I'm going to try and add and invoke later
};

void Child::Init()
{
    Register_Command_Function_Pair("TestFunction", &Child::Foo);
}

void Child::Foo(vector<string> parms)
{
    cout << "Calling Foo\n";
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = parms.begin(); it != parms.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Example use of code:

```
int main()
{
    Child c;
    c.Init();

    vector<string> arguments;
    arguments.push_back("Testing");
    arguments.push_back("123");
    c.Run_Script_Command("TestFunction", arguments);

    // Expected output:
    // Calling Foo
    // Testing
    // 123  
}
```

I've tried to create a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, so hopefully my goal makes sense, even if there are some otherwise poor design decisions (made for the sake of the example).

How can I get this to compile and give me the expected output?

Thanks.

EDIT:  The above code should throw the following compiler error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(506): error C2664: 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>> *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>> *'
          with
          [
              _Ret=void
  ,            _Ty=std::string
          ]
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Fret(__cdecl Child::* const &)(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>),_Alloc>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ret=void
  ,            _Ty=std::string
  ,            _Fret=void
  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>
  ,            _Fty=void (__cdecl Child::* const &)(std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>)
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Fret(__cdecl Child::* const &)(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>),_Alloc>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ret=void
  ,            _Ty=std::string
  ,            _Fret=void
  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>
  ,            _Fty=void (__cdecl Child::* const &)(std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>)
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::_Reset_alloc<_Fret,Child,std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>>(_Fret (__cdecl Child::* const )(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>),_Alloc)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ret=void
  ,            _Ty=std::string
  ,            _Fret=void
  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(442) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::_Reset_alloc<_Fret,Child,std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>>(_Fret (__cdecl Child::* const )(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>),_Alloc)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ret=void
  ,            _Ty=std::string
  ,            _Fret=void
  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>>
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::_Reset<void,Child,std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>(_Fret (__cdecl Child::* const )(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>))' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ret=void
  ,            _Ty=std::string
  ,            _Fret=void
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::_Reset<void,Child,std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>(_Fret (__cdecl Child::* const )(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>))' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ret=void
  ,            _Ty=std::string
  ,            _Fret=void
          ]
          Source\GoDatabase.cpp(3436) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>)>::function<void(__cdecl Child::* )(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>)>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::string
  ,            _Fx=void (__cdecl Child::* )(std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>)
          ]
          Source\GoDatabase.cpp(3436) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (const IScriptable &,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>)>::function<void(__cdecl Child::* )(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>)>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::string
  ,            _Fx=void (__cdecl Child::* )(std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>)
          ]
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Compiler errors.  I can post what this specific example throws up on, but I've tried many different syntactical variations and methods, each with compiler errors.  I'm hoping a general solution can be provided to accomplish what I tried to outline above.

Comment: Edited to add compiler errors thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function type should be:

```
std::function<void(std::vector<std::string>)>
```

`const IScriptable&` does not work there, if you want to use pointer to method, that would be completely different syntax.

Then `Init()` could be this:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
Register_Command_Function_Pair("TestFunction", std::bind( &Child::Foo, this, _1 ) );
```

`Run_Script_Command()` becomes:

```
bool IScriptable::Run_Script_Command(string i_Command, vector<string> i_Arguments)
{
    auto f = m_Command_Functions.find(i_Command);
    if ( f != m_Command_Functions.end())
    {
        f->second(i_Arguments);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note you should create type alias (either by `typedef` or `using`) for `std::function` you are using, as you use it multiple times. That will make code more readable and change that type much easier.